# CSS position elements in way that only element is visible at a time regardless of screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to position charts on a page. Here is screenshot for you to have a look.

[image]

I want it so that only one element (chart) is visible at a time. I know margin and padding stuff. But i do not think that will work for all resolutions.

What you suggest?

Comment: and/or a drawing how you want it to be

Comment: How do you want toggle between charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PWXG6/)**

```
<ul>
    <li id="one"><a href="#one">one</a><a href="#two">two</a><a href="#three">three</a></li>
    <li id="two"><a href="#one">one</a><a href="#two">two</a><a href="#three">three</a></li>
    <li id="three"><a href="#one">one</a><a href="#two">two</a><a href="#three">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

### (Relevant) CSS

```
li
{
    width: 100vw; /* 100% of viewport width */
    height: 100vh; /* 100% of viewport height*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use jQuery tabs.

For this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/Ay665/) I copied the code directly from jQuery UI site and modified it.

HTML

```
<div class='charts'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Daily Use</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Monthly Use</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Annual Use</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
      <div class='chart1'>This is your daily use of electricity</div>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
      <div class='chart2'>This is your monthly use of electricity</div>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-3">
      <div class='chart3'>This is your annual use of electricity</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `display` property (references are available in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) and [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)) to make one of the charts invisible when you show the other. For example:

**CSS**

```
.visible {
    display: block;
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="visible">This text is visible.</div>
<div class="invisible">But this one isn't.</div>
<div class="invisible">Neither is this one.</div>
<div class="visible">But this is. :)</div>
```

Take a look in the demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gnCV/).

Comment: Display none will not leave the space and also this may not be the solution for this question.

Comment: It wasn't said that the space should remain reserved. And I understood that this is what he/she wanted.